# How to parse multiple elements in portions for html via Simple Html Dom

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am attempting to get various elements inside of an li as shown below. I am pretty new to this so I may not be using the most efficient methods but this is where I have started...

EXAMPLE CODE SIMPLIFIED....

```
<li id='entry_0' title='09879879'>
    <div ....>
        <h2> The title text would go here </h2>
        <span class='entrySize' ....> 20oz </span>
        <span class='entryPrice' ....> $32.09 </span>
        <span class='anotherEntry' ....> More Data I need To Grab </span>
        .......
    </div>
</li>

<li> .... With same structure as above .... 100's of entries like this </li>
```

I know how to pull individual parts separately but having trouble grasping how to do it grouped within a portion of the html.

```
$filename = "directory/file.html";
$html = file_get_html($filename);

for($i=0; $i<=count(entryNumber);$i++)
{
    $li_id = "entry_".$i;
    foreach($html->find('li[id='.$li_id.']') as $li) {         
        echo $li->innertext;
    }
}
```

So this gets me the content in the line item tag with the id number as the unique attribute. I would like to grab the h2 text, entrySize, entryPrice etc as I iterate through the line item tags. What I don't understand is once I have the line item tag content how can I parse through that line item inner tags and attributes. There maybe other parts of the full HTML document that has tags with same id, class as these throughout the document so I am breaking this down to portions and than looking to parse each section at a time.

I would also like to pull the title attribute out of the title tag for the li tag.

I hope my explanation make sense.

Comment: I am testing out some code and by adding.....

echo $li->title

I was able to get the title value out of it. Still working on the other elements / tags within the line item tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a DOM parser. PHP comes bundled with one, and there are many other's you could use.

http://php.net/dom

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
<?php
$html = file_get_content($page);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// now find what you need
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $id = $item->getAttribute('id');
    if (strpos($id, 'item_') !== false) {
        // found matchin li, grab its children
    }
}
```

Use this as a baseline, we can't write all the code for you. Check out the PHP docs to finish this :) From what I have so far, you need to follow the docs to make it grab the child values, and handle them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Very helpful.